# How to make Modularization in Flutter to separate each application feature

Tags: flutter, modularization

On Android native to separate each application feature, structured the project, implementing architecture component and to make it easier to work in a team you can use modularization, so each person can focus on their respective work by focusing only on the module. If I want to make a flutter application with examples of 3 application features (login, register, profile) and want to implement modularization for each feature to make it easier to work as a team. How do you implement the modular? Are there references to its best practices for modularizing Flutter? Because if on Android Native there are already many related articles while I check for Flutter it hasn't found it yet.

Comment: You can take a look at the BLOC pattern in Flutter. You can also watch some of the latest FilledStacks videos on YouTube which explain how to modularize your application.

Comment: Yes, I already implement it. But I want to make each feature of application as modular and then call each modular to the root of project ex: lib/main.dart. It's possible to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create each feature as a package(library) and add it whenever you want to the main app. For example in my app I use main.dart as a navigator manager and each screen is in different packages.

And this is an example of implementing it: https://github.com/rrifafauzikomara/flutter_modularization

Comment: Yes, Actually I have already implemented it, thanks for the answer bro